# git completion broken by bash profile alias 'test'

Tags: bash, git, macos

I had an alias in my bash profile like this:

`alias test='cd /Usr/work/dir/test'`

every time I would try to use bash completion for git in a terminal it would:

1. freeze the terminal immediately after hitting tab.
2. take me to that directory.

As soon as I removed that alias bash completion for git works fine. Why's that?

git version 2.26.2

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Also, don't use aliases.  They've been effectively obsolete since before 1996.  Use a function.

Answer (score 3):

`test` is a built-in command, and creating an alias named `test` shadows it, which could lead to unforeseen issues. Pick a different name.

```
alias goto_test='cd /Usr/work/dir/test'
```

However, this is probably the *least* desirable solution. First, consider using a function instead:

```
goto_test () {
    cd /Usr/work/dir/test
}
```

Second, you can add `/Usr/work/dir` to your `CDPATH` variable, so that you can quickly switch to *any* subdirectory without having to use the entire path.

```
$ CDPATH=/Usr/work/dir
$ cd test
/Usr/Work/dir
$ pwd
/Usr/Work/dir/test
```

This saves you from having to define multiple aliases or functions if there are several directories you might commonly switch to.